# How to upload all the images on the server from a selected folder in SD card

Tags: android, image-uploading

I have created an application in which I am saving the image taken from the camera in a folder on SD card.Now I want to upload all the images inside that folder on the server at once. I am able to get all the images as bitmap from the folder and stored it in `ArrayList`. Now I want to send these images on the server.but I am in doubt whether I have to send all the images in one request or should I send it one by one. I have successfully uploaded one image by converting the image into `Base64 String`.I also have to display the progress of uploading.Please help me in deciding what to do with some examples.

Comment: Send the files one by one.